# NumPy interp equivalent in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I need to call external functions for writing an equality constraint in Pyomo. I understand that everything must be symbolic, so I was thinking about providing a set of x and y values and using something like to `numpy.interp`. Is there equivalent function in Pyomo for this simple example:

```py
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [3, 2, 0]
>>> np.interp(2.5, x, y)
1.0
```

I saw Pyomo [Piecewise Functions](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library_reference/kernel/piecewise/piecewise.html) and perhaps this could do this, but I don't know how to proceed. Any help is greatly appreciated.